# How to take back my bounty and give it to the right answerer?

Tags: support, bounty

I have set a bounty for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206581/how-to-check-for-webpages-popups). 2 users answered me, I accepted one answer only because it is exactly what I need. But I did not gave the bounty to the answerer who helped me a lot. I feel shame of myself. Is there any way to give them back to the user for whom I accepted the answer ?

Comment: Don't worry about it.  alecxe has more than 47500 rep points already.  The 100 you were offering are not going to matter to him :)

Comment: Yes, but it is just a question of being fair or unfair with people who helped me without knowing me.

Comment: that's very considerate of you but really, don't worry about it.  the experienced users here are very used to helping out without getting anything in return other than some brain exercise.

Comment: The brain exercise is often the biggest reward. But we do appreciate it when you throw us an upvote!

Comment: As a sidenote, avoid _summoning_ people who answer your question [to look into your other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206581/how-to-check-for-webpages-popups#comment37487853_24243985). I know your intentions are good, but it not not an advisable behaviour. And yeah, don't worry about the bounty, reputation doesn't matter. The joy of writing a good answer is more rewarding. The best way to say thanks is by helping someone else in future, just like s/he helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start **another** bounty on the question and award it to the other answer.

Though that requires that the bounty is **bigger** than the last one.

---

There is no way to **revoke** an already awarded bounty.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: This answer is good, because once I will get 150 points I will do what is explained on this answer.